# Stopping debugging in one Visual Studio instance stops debugging in all other instances

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2022

Basically the title, e.g. I have two different solutions in two different windows of Visual Studio, I run debugging on both. Then I stop debugging in one of them and it also stops debugging in the other one.
Also happens with Visual Studio Code - as if all the debuggers were linked somehow...

Comment: what language? C++? C#? what language extensions in VS Code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This turned out to be really obscure, but basically it was caused by a combination of settings in both Visual Studios.

Visual Studio 2022 was set to launch browser window on debug, and to stop debugging when the window was closed. Visual Studio Code also launched a browser window (to debug the app I am working on), and obviously that also stops debugging when the window is closed. So stopping debugging in *either* would close the browser window, thus stopping debugging in the other one.

Comment: it's still not clear to me... they both opened a tab in the same browser window, and instead of closing their own tabs, they closed the whole window?

Comment: tbh I'm not entirely certain myself, but I have disabled the default behaviour to "stop debugging when browser window is closed" and the issue went away, so...

Answer (score -1):

You can try what is suggested here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging under multi-target debugging.

Are you in multi-target mode when you launch multiple sessions?

You should be able to select the session from the Dropdown menu and click stop that way.

There’s another method under compound launch configurations as well.

Have you tried both these methods?

Comment: You were not even close, turns out it was a more obscure problem, see my own answer, but your answer did help me find out my issue, so when I can, I will award you the bounty. Thanks for trying :)